# Angular Material $mdDialog.hide() - use nested controller selection in main controller promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, mddialog

I have an `$mdDialog` window that is popping up at one click and then, based on the user's choice, another window opens containing a Select list so that the user can select a particular month of the year. I need to capture this month selection from the second window and use it further in an AJAX request. The problem is that I only found solutions that say that you need to set the promise inside the `$mdDialog.show()` and then resolve it in `$mdDialog.hide()`.

The problem is that I have $mdDialog.hide() in the nested controller and so I feel like I am trying to put the carriage in front of the horses here.
This is part of my controller where you can see the nested controller with the `.hide()` action. Of course it returns 'undefined' now...

```
angular
    .module('demoApp')
    .controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', function($scope, $mdDialog){
    $scope.showConfirm = function(event) {
    $mdDialog.show({
        targetEvent: event,
        templateUrl: 'templates/mainDialogTemplate.html',
        controller: function($scope, $mdDialog, employee){
           $scope.employee = employee;
           $scope.closeDialog = function(){$mdDialog.hide();}
           $scope.pickDate = function(){$mdDialog.show({
                    templateUrl: 'templates/calendarDialogTemplate.html',
                    parent: angular.element(document.body),
                    //clickOutsideToClose: true,
                    controller: function($scope, $mdDialog) {
                        $scope.cancel = function(){$mdDialog.cancel();}
                        $scope.months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
                        $scope.closeDialog = function(){$mdDialog.hide(answer)};
                    }
           }).then(function(answer){
                  console.log(answer);
           })
        }
```